# Could not import cufflinks and plotly on jupyter notebook even though it has already been installed on cmd

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, cufflinks

I have already `pip install cufflinks` and `pip install plotly` on my cmd but I still could not import it to my Jupiter notebook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

conda install -c bioconda cufflinks

Comment: Hi, i have tried but this shows up

C:\Users\Acer>conda install -c bioconda cufflinks
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.